# Lagrangian with two nonzero constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Determine the maximum value of $OP$, $O$ being the origin and $P$ being a point on the curve defined by $x^2+y^2-2z^2=5$ and $x+2y+z=5$.

I am using Lagrangian multipliers $\lambda$ and $\mu$. I have done problems in which one of the constraints goes to zero. Here both are non-zero. How will we eliminate them from the differential equation?

Comment: Try eliminating the first multiplier through manipulating fractions. Then use the given constraints to eliminate the second.

Comment: or else just use partial derivatives and utilize the function paramater for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grit your teeth and grind through the solution. It’s really not all that involved and requires at worst solving a simple quadratic equation. Besides the two constraints, you have the equations $$2x-2\lambda x -\mu = 0 \\ 2y-2\lambda y-2\mu = 0 \\ 2z+4\lambda z - \mu = 0.$$ You should be able to see at a glance that $\mu$ can be eliminated by forming various linear combinations of these equations. For example, if you subtract twice the first from the second, the result factors nicely into $$2(2x-y)(\lambda-1) = 0.$$ Now you have two possibilities to pursue. Back-substitute each in turn into your system of equations and continue solving. (It turns out that one of these two paths leads to $\mu=0$. One of the multipliers vanishes after all.)

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

We can convert $x^2+y^2-2z^2=5$ to  $x^2+y^2-2z^2-5=0$. Let $g_1(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-2z^2-5$.

Perform similar trick for the second constraint.

Hence now, you have reduced the problem to an expression that you are familiar with $$\max_{x,y,z} f(x)$$ subject to $$g_1(x,y,z)=0$$ $$g_2(x,y,z)=0.$$

Comment: That I know, I have done problems. But you see in most of these problems one of the contraints equals to zero, just check in this site itself for similar problems. So that after taking partial derivatives and manipulating the fractions we are able to eliminate one of the lambda or mu. But here since both constraints are nonzero, so Im unable to eliminate neither of lamda or mu from the partial derivative equations.

Comment: can you include your attempt in your post?

Comment: @Fulcrum You happened to get lucky in those other problems. In general, the multipliers will be non-zero and their values sometimes have physical or geometrical significance. Plug in the values you’re getting and keep solving.

Answer (score 1):

Computers were invented for a reason! Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) to solve the system of polynomial equations:

```
from sympy import *

x, y, z, mu1, mu2 = symbols('x y z mu1 mu2', real=True)

# define Lagrangian
L = (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) - mu1 * (x**2 + y**2 - 2*z**2 - 5) - mu2 * (x + 2*y + z - 5)

# compute partial derivatives
partials = [ diff(L,var) for var in [x, y, z, mu1, mu2] ]

# find where partial derivatives vanish
print solve_poly_system(partials, x, y, z, mu1, mu2)
```

This script outputs the following list of solutions.

```
[(1, 2, 0, 1, 0), (11/9, 22/9, -10/9, -7/3, 220/27)]
```

Plotting the [hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid), the plane, and points $(1, 2, 0)$ and $\left( \frac{11}{9}, \frac{22}{9}, -\frac{10}{9} \right)$, we have

[image]

Comment: sorry mine was a pure mathematical question, i dont need an answer using a script.